# aspx page showing old master page even after changing in page directive

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

This is either a weird behavior or I am doing something wrong here.
I have an aspx page with an associated Master page. I want to replace this master page with a new one.

The following steps I followed:

1. I created a new master page and added the same html from the old one.
2. I replaced `MasterPageFile` attribute in the page directive.

I thought this should work but it is not. It is still showing the old master page.
Now, when I replace the `MasterPageFile` from code it works.

```
public DefaultNew()
{
    this.PreInit += new EventHandler(DefaultNew_PreInit);
}

void DefaultNew_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPageFile = "~/_Master/MasterPageNew.Master";
}
```

I have rebuilt the code, closed Visual Studio and restarted but in Vain.

An ideas? Please help.

Comment: Does this page inherit something like say a BasePage class? Maybe the master page is set in it. Also you don't show how you set the actual attribute.

Comment: OMG!! Yes it had a bage class and preinit was overriden there. And it was setting the masterpage there. Thanks for the direction. If you please put your comment in as answer, i will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have a base class for the page that happens to sets the master page for all pages that derive from it.